# ios8 UIImagePickerController Orientation

Tags: orientation, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8

Using UIImagePickerController to take pictures and video
The app starts in LandscapeRight, and the Camera image is correct
Rotate the device clockwise and the camera image rotates anti clockwise (Top is to the left)
Rotate the device again clockwise and the camera image rotates anti clockwise again (now upside down)
The only image that is correct is the image when in LandscapeRight

Anyone come across this and now how to keep the camera oriented to the top when the device rotates

Thanks in advance